# Dynamically adding duplicate (unique ID) form Div elements using javascript

Tags: java, javascript, spring, jsp, dojo

I have a form having fields like:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="field">
      <input class="" type="text" name="college" id="college"/>
   </div>

   <div class="field">
      <input class="" type="text" name="city" id="city"/>
   </div>

   <div class="field">
      <input class="" type="text" name="zip" id="zip"/>
   </div>
</div>
<input type="button" class="buttonWidth" id="btnAddressAdd" value="Add Worksite Addressess"/>
```

I have a Add extra address button that add's another copy of div "row" to the page. I need to send all data from the page as a request to the Controller. How do I write a script that add's extra div copy onclick of the button and also appends a unique id to each of the new fields?

Comment: Do you use javascript-frameworks like jQuery or Prototype?

Comment: I am working into a code base that uses plain javascript and DOJO for their inbuilt functions. I would have to stick to these coding practices itself. :(

Comment: retagged to dojo, those freaks will help you so hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See working example in **Dojo**: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/PeQCN/

And the same code in **plain vanilla JavaScript**: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/Rceua/

The Dojo version employs `dojo/_base/lang::clone` as @Peter Rader mentioned:

```
// var lang    = require("dojo/_base/lang");
// var array   = require("dojo/_base/array");
// var query   = require("dojo/query");
// var domAttr = require("dojo/dom-attr");

var counter = 0;

function duplicate(/*Node*/sourceNode, /*Array*/attributesToBump) {
    counter++;
    var out = lang.clone(sourceNode);
    if (domAttr.has(out, "id")) { out.id = bump(out.id); }

    query("*", out).forEach(function(node) {
        array.forEach(attributesToBump, function(attribute) {
            if (domAttr.has(node, attribute)) {
                domAttr.set(node, attribute, bump(domAttr.get(node, attribute)));
            }        
        })
    });

    function bump(/*String*/str) {
        return str + "_" + counter;
    }

    return out;
}
```

How to use the aforementioned `duplicate` function:

```
// var dom          = require("dojo/dom");
// var domConstruct = require("dojo/dom-construct");

var sourceNode = dom.byId("fieldset");
var node = duplicate(sourceNode, ["id", "name", "placeholder"]);  
domConstruct.place(node, sourceNode, "after");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written code to achieve this.

Logic:
1) get the innerHTML of desired parent
2) replace id in the text
3) Insert the new html

See a [working code](http://jsbin.com/ulipeg/5/watch)

Pardon me for bad style of coding on JS part. I am not use to coding directly on DOM. I prefer JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Try

to use this snipplet (see usage)
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/_base/lang.html#dojo-base-lang-clone